# awk system does not take hyphens

Tags: linux, shell, awk, cat

I want to redirect the output of some command to awk and use system call in awk. But Awk does not accept flags with hyphen. For example, Lets say I have bunch of files, and I want to "cat" them. I would use `ls -1 | awk '{ system(" cat " $1)}'`

Now, if I want to print the line number also with `-n` then it does not work `ls -1 | awk '{ system(" cat -n" $1)}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a space between `-n` and the file name:

```
ls -1 | awk '{ system(" cat -n " $1)}'
```

#### Notes

- `-1` is not needed.  `ls` implicitly prints 1 file per line when its output goes to a pipe.
- Any file name with whitespace in it will cause this code to fail.
- Parsing the output of `ls` is generally [a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Both `find` and the shell offer superior handling of difficult file names.

Comment: **IF** you were ever really going to do this (which you would not do for this task) then it should be written as `ls -1 | awk '{ system("cat -n \047" $1 "\047")}'` to protect from globbing, variable expansion, file name expansion, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[John1024's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37083858/45375) fixes your problem and contains helpful advice, but let me focus on the *syntax* aspects:

As a command *string*, `cat -n <file>` requires at least 1 space (or tab) between the `n`, which is an *option*, and `<file>`, which is an *operand*.

String concatenation works *differently* in `awk` than in the shell:

`" cat -n" $1`, despite the presence of a space between `" cat -n"` and `$1`, does *not* insert that space in the resulting string, because **`awk`'s string concatenation works by directly joining strings placed next to one another *irrespective of intervening whitespace*.**

For instance, the following commands all yield string literal `ab`, irrespective of any whitespace between the operands of the string concatenation:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "a""b" }'
awk 'BEGIN { print "a"         "b" }'
awk 'BEGIN { s = "b"; print "a"s }'
awk 'BEGIN { s = "b"; print "a"          s }'
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not a proper use case for `awk`, you're better off with something like this

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cat -n {} \;
```

Comment: Given the use of `ls -1` in the question, the line `cat *` should do the job.

Comment: Thank you karakfa ,@John1024. I was acutualy trying to use this with qstat command  of job scheduler TORQUE. 

qstat |grep "R normal" | awk '{system(" qstat -f " $1 "| grep -E \"Remaining|nodes\" ")}'

Comment: `cat *` will have one long sequence, won't reset line numbers per file.

Comment: @karakfa: That is true of _GNU_ `cat` (which is apt, given that this question is tagged `linux`), but, as a point of interest, _BSD_ `cat` (at least the version that comes with OS X 10.11.4) numbers the input files' lines _per file_ with `cat -n`.

Comment: @user2958481 that command line you put in your comment is completely the wrong way to do what you are trying to do. Awk is not a shell so using it as such to call shell commands is obviously a bad idea. There are many other ways in which the command line you are trying to run is wrong too, conceptually and syntactically- if you post a followup question with concise, testable sample input (the output of qstat) and expected output then we can help you.